# is "where's that' correct?

Tags: speech

I was at school and my teacher asked us to look for something in our book. Then a lot of people started asking "Where's that at?", but I heard one person say "Where's that?", and someone immediately "corrected" him by saying "Where's that at". Was the kid's statement grammatically correct? I know "Where's it" and "Where's he" are incorrect, but what about "Where's that?". Was his apostrophed phrase correct?

Comment: Yessss, it's correct..

Comment: I can see you are a young student so I will help  you here. The "at" is wrong. Where's that? The preposition at is redundant since where already asks for a location. The person you heard was wrong. That said, people do go around putting "at" everything like that. [This question will be closed or moved to ELL].

Comment: Adding "at" is correct.

Comment: @Lambie - And there's the rule of Engish construction:  "Never use a preposition to end a sentence with."

Comment: @Hot Licks Nope. It has nothing to do with that. It has to do with **meaning**. If I say: Where is he? Answer: He's **at school**. **There is no need for at in the question**! That is very different from: I don't know what he sings **about**. **That** is what your truism corresponds to. [sings about, corresponds to]

Comment: @Bob Putting  "at" is completely redundant. What time did he arrive **at**? There **at** is fine. It is **not redundant**.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that there is controversy over this sentence. And the proposed duplicate does not address the main question here which is the 'at'. I think that means it is very appropriate for ELU, and should be reopened.

Comment: @Mitch Yep, and you can lead a horse to water but you can't make him drink.

Comment: "where's that at?" is common in colloquial English, especially in the US. People who say it is incorrect mean they don't like it, not that native English speakers don't say it. You could argue that "at" is unnecessary but that's a matter of style, and sometimes it's useful to use unnecessary words to communicate more clearly. (Although "where's that" is fine.)

Comment: @StuartF Did I say incorrect? I said it is redundant. Frankly, I find it somewhat uneducated. I immediately know the person is then likely to say She don't and He don't, also uneducated but that does not mean they ain't sticking to the vernacular. They most certainly are. Praise be. [ha ha] I don't begrudge anyone their speech habits.

Comment: @Bob "Where's that at" is incorrect in standard English but there are many dialects both in the UK and the US which use it. Obviously you are a speaker of one of those dialects.

Comment: @BoldBen "Citation required". :)

Comment: @tchrist Do you mean a citation in favour of the "where's that at" being incorrect in standard English or in favour of it's being a part of certain dialects?

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are a young student so I will help you here. The "at" is wrong.

> Example:  Where's that? The preposition *at* is *redundant* since
> *where* already asks for a location. The person you heard was wrong. That said, people do go around putting "at" in tons of utterances like
> that: Where's he at? *Instead of*: *Where is he*? He's at school right
> now.

It's the answer to a question with "where is x" that takes the **at**, not the question.